# Is fulfillment based on emotional or logical obligations?

Tags: sharia, knowing-islam

All praise be to Almighty Allah,

Asalamu Aleykum, I was having a question in my mind. I have no knowledge about Islam at all, In Shaa Allah one day I will have.

**My question** is during the fulfilment of our duties to Allah(S.W.T), does emotion count as an effort or do you have to be logical and do it?

For example, when we are commanded to do something, for example, zakkat, we have to do it even if we don't like it. My point is most sharia are like the law you don't say I like this law or I don't like this law you have to do it. ***So does emotion play any role if the fulfilment of Islamic law?***

Let's say you are doing something for the benefit of helping others but you don't like it but for the fear of God you have to do it, does that count as good deeds?

I apologize for my English am using a translator.

Comment: There are multiple questions in your question; "does emotion play any role in the fulfilment of Islamic law?" , ..... "does  that count as good"  deeds?

Comment: @AbduRahman yes yes yes can you educate me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Walaikum assalaam.

There are two types of 'emotions':

1. Built-in emotions.. these exist in every single human being.

Like hating hunger and thirst, hating to fight in a war, etc... You can't get rid of this type of emotions, Allah -Almighty- said to Sahabas and to all Muslims:

> كُتب عليكم القتال وهو كرهٌ لكم وعسى أن تكرهوا شيئاً وهو خيرٌ لكم

*Translation: "Jihad (holy fighting in Allah's Cause) is ordained for you (Muslims) though you dislike it, and it may be that you dislike a thing which is good for you".*

2. Gained and acquired emotions, in this type, for the same subject, emotions differ from one person to another.

Usually, Emotion of this type is in contrasts to obeying and surrender, and the person wonders and wishes if this or that 'law' in particular is not exist..

This type of emotions could lead to Kufr or cause to make all the doings as if they does not exist

> ذلك بأنّهم كرهوا ما أنزل الله فأحبط أعمالهم

*Translation: "That is because they hate that which Allah has sent down (this Quran and Islamic laws) so He has made their deeds fruitless."*

**The point is that**: as long as your heart is saying: "I accept (and will accept) all of Allah's orders, and I will go against myself to do what Allah wants me to do, and I will do it for Allah only and not for anybody, not for people and not seeking any Donia benefit".. **then**, you will be rewarded twice -Insha'Allah-:

1. one for the doing itself,
2. and the other for self Jihad and loyalty.

Almighty Allah knows, may Allah guide us all.

Comment: Ma Shaa Allah Sulaiman, May God Bless you and your family, But the second option I think has to do with the desire not Emotional. Because pleasure is derived from sensational and sensational is derived from desire and desire from thought and thought control thinking and thinking create time. because thinking is an iteration of the collection of memory, so It's not gained emotion it's gained desire. This is my own opinion don't feel offended My brother

Comment: desire it's not real it's something that created on our mind but emotional it is real its associated with experience, that's why we are been told to feel empathy for certain people and not feel desire.

Comment: Yes, "Gained and acquired emotions" is not well-formed. Emotions can not be gained by itself, but you got the meaning.. I was expressing "emotions that happend as consequences after thinking process, which is gained".. 

"The second option I think has to do with the desire not Emotional".. Acutally, I think that emotions and desires are related, refer to the verse in the second paragraph.. at first, it might be desires, but when time goes on, it will just be emotions of hate or joy (I'd like to cite [39:45](https://quran.com/39?startingVerse=45)), Hypocrites are full of hate, automatically!

Comment: May Almighty Allah bless you, my brother, for sharing knowledge with me.